# Using gettext to localize a mono multithreaded server application

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono, gettext, server

I'm trying to get gettext to work in a multithreaded server environment, where the server will localize strings based on the clients locale.

I'm basing my POC code on this example: http://www.mono-project.com/archived/internationalization. My implementation of the sample seems to be correct. Running my code on the command line like this:
`LANGUAGE=da_DK mono Test.exe` produces `Mit navn er Enzo`

Given the following code:

```
using System;
using Mono.Unix;
using Mono.Unix.Native;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Test
{
    public class Locale : IDisposable
    {
        static class LocaleCategory
        {
            public const int LC_CTYPE          = 0;
            public const int LC_NUMERIC        = 1;
            public const int LC_TIME           = 2;
            public const int LC_COLLATE        = 3;
            public const int LC_MONETARY       = 4;
            public const int LC_MESSAGES       = 5;
            public const int LC_ALL            = 6;
            public const int LC_PAPER          = 7;
            public const int LC_NAME           = 8;
            public const int LC_ADDRESS        = 9;
            public const int LC_TELEPHONE      = 10;
            public const int LC_MEASUREMENT    = 11;
            public const int LC_IDENTIFICATION = 12;
        }

        [Flags]
        enum LocaleMask
        {
            LC_CTYPE_MASK          = (1 << LocaleCategory.LC_CTYPE),
            LC_NUMERIC_MASK        = (1 << LocaleCategory.LC_NUMERIC),
            LC_TIME_MASK           = (1 << LocaleCategory.LC_TIME),
            LC_COLLATE_MASK        = (1 << LocaleCategory.LC_COLLATE),
            LC_MONETARY_MASK       = (1 << LocaleCategory.LC_MONETARY),
            LC_MESSAGES_MASK       = (1 << LocaleCategory.LC_MESSAGES),
            LC_PAPER_MASK          = (1 << LocaleCategory.LC_PAPER),
            LC_NAME_MASK           = (1 << LocaleCategory.LC_NAME),
            LC_ADDRESS_MASK        = (1 << LocaleCategory.LC_ADDRESS),
            LC_TELEPHONE_MASK      = (1 << LocaleCategory.LC_TELEPHONE),
            LC_MEASUREMENT_MASK    = (1 << LocaleCategory.LC_MEASUREMENT),
            LC_IDENTIFICATION_MASK = (1 << LocaleCategory.LC_IDENTIFICATION),
            LC_ALL = LC_CTYPE_MASK|LC_NUMERIC_MASK|LC_TIME_MASK|LC_COLLATE_MASK|LC_MONETARY_MASK|LC_MESSAGES_MASK|
                     LC_PAPER_MASK|LC_NAME_MASK|LC_ADDRESS_MASK|LC_TELEPHONE_MASK|LC_MEASUREMENT_MASK|LC_IDENTIFICATION_MASK
        }

        [DllImport ("libc", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern IntPtr newlocale (Int32 categoryMask, IntPtr locale, IntPtr baseLocale);

        [DllImport ("libc", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern IntPtr duplocale (IntPtr locale);

        [DllImport ("libc", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern IntPtr uselocale (IntPtr newLocale);


        [DllImport ("libc", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern IntPtr freelocale (IntPtr localObj);

        IntPtr m_oldLocale;
        IntPtr m_newLocale;

        IntPtr LC_GLOBAL_LOCALE;

        ApplicationException BuildException(string message)
        {
            Errno errno = Stdlib.GetLastError ();
            return new ApplicationException(string.Format (message + ": {0}:{1}", errno, Stdlib.strerror (errno)));
        }

        public Locale(string localeName)
        {
            LC_GLOBAL_LOCALE = new IntPtr (-1);

            IntPtr marshalledLocaleName = UnixMarshal.StringToHeap (localeName);
            if (marshalledLocaleName == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw BuildException("Error marshalling string");

            try{
                IntPtr duplicateGlobal = duplocale(LC_GLOBAL_LOCALE);
                if(duplicateGlobal == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw BuildException("Error duplicating global");

                m_newLocale = newlocale ((Int32)LocaleMask.LC_MESSAGES_MASK, marshalledLocaleName, duplicateGlobal);

                if(m_newLocale == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw BuildException(string.Format("Error getting locale '{0}'", localeName));

                m_oldLocale = uselocale (m_newLocale);
                if(m_oldLocale == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw BuildException("Error using locale");
            }
            finally {
                UnixMarshal.FreeHeap (marshalledLocaleName);
            }
        }

        ~Locale() 
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose (true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize (this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (m_newLocale != IntPtr.Zero && m_oldLocale != IntPtr.Zero) 
            {
                uselocale(m_oldLocale);
                freelocale (m_newLocale);
                m_newLocale = IntPtr.Zero;
                m_oldLocale = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            using (Locale l = new Locale ("da_DK")) {
                Catalog.Init ("i18n", "./locale");
                Console.WriteLine (Catalog.GetString ("My name is {0}"), "Enzo");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would have expected:

`mono Text.exe` to produce the same output, but ... it doesn't, instead it produces: `My name is Enzo`. Clearly the code doesn't set the thread locale correctly, but I cannot see where my mistake is.

My question is: What am I doing wrong?
and as a follow up: Do I really need to add the locales prior to using them?
I.e. I had to add the danish local like this:

`sudo locale-gen da_DK
sudo update-locale`

PS: Eventually this code will integrate with Mono.Addins, which uses gettext, so I'm pretty much stuck with this technology.

Comment: I'm not sure gettext is a good option for a web application (as opposed to a desktop app); maybe you can have more luck if you use https://github.com/rdio/vernacular

Comment: Problem is, support for gettext is built into mono addins, and gettext has the best tooling support.